# C# Listview adding item with image and text, and align the text to left

Tags: c#, image, text, listitem

I'm trying to create some test programs, just for fun to learn c#, and I came to something I really couldn't figure out.

I wanted to add an image to an item in a listview. I found an article on Stackoverflow explaining how to do this, and it worked. However, I cannot add extra text to the item. I'd like to have an image with text next to it. My current code:

```
ImageList Imagelist = new ImageList();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //retrieve all image files
        String[] ImageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test");
        foreach (var file in ImageFiles)
        {
            //Add images to Imagelist
            Imagelist.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file));
        }
        //set the amall and large ImageList properties of listview
        listView1.LargeImageList = Imagelist;
        listView1.SmallImageList = Imagelist;

        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { ImageIndex = 0});
    }
```

Obviously it will only add one image, it's meant to. Anyway, how would I enter text next to the image? For example

```
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { ImageIndex = 0} "Image 1");
```

The text must be located behind the image.

I've also got a second question.
I do not have columns (adding them doesn't do the trick either). I would like to have the item aligned to the left side of the ListView. How could I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Short answer: switch to WPF. This can be done in less than 10 minutes using a `DataTemplate`.

Comment: @programmer93 - Thanks. However, I'm not sure if I'm able to make this dynamic via XAML. Eventually I am going to use MySQL and make the script add a list item based on the results.

Comment: You don't have to do this in XAML. You can still use the code-behind. In any case, yes this can be done in XAML as well as in the code-behind.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should solve your problems.

```
listView1.View = View.Details; // Enables Details view so you can see columns
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 0, Text = "Image 1" }); // Using object initializer to add the text
```

Comment: Thank you Zicore! It solved my problems. However, there's one question I'd like to ask. Is it possible to lock the column so it cannot be resized?