# how to load thumbnails in listview as needed?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, imagelist

So I want to be able to populate 1000s of thumbnails based on a list of image filepaths.  I tried using the following code but I realized that after the 200+ image, my program would throw me a "A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll".

```
private void PopulateThumbnails(List<string> queryResults)
{
    this.playerListView.Items.Clear();
    this.imageList1.Images.Clear();
    ImageViewer imageViewer = new ImageViewer();

    foreach (string file in queryResults)
    {
        try
            this.imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file));
        catch
            Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
    }

    this.ListView.View = View.LargeIcon;
    this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(256, 144);
    this.ListView.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;

    for (int j = 0; j < this.imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.ImageIndex = j;
        this.ListView.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

I realize that I should probably only populate the thumbnails as needed but...
a) how do I know how many items are being loaded in the listview?
b) how do I detect scroll events in listview?

Comment: do a google search on how to add thumbnail or images to a ListViewItem here is a previous `SO` Posting in the meantime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151776/c-sharp-listview-adding-item-with-image-and-text-and-align-the-text-to-left

Comment: well my problem is not knowing HOW to add thumbnails. It works as is.  My problem occurs when I add TOO MANY thumbnails.

Comment: how about debugging the code perhaps there is something else going on that you are not aware of.. maybe you need to free the item in this line after you add the item to the ListView.Items `ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();` but I bet that you may discover something once you step thru the code

Comment: I did debug the code...it gets stuck on this line "this.imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file));" if I add to many thumbnails.  If I cut the list to 100 everything works perfectly fine.  The problem is that it runs out of memory.  Which is why I'm trying not to draw ALL of them.

Comment: well for starters I would refactor the code in your try{}catch{} and add some valid Exception handling and write to the console or some file what the actual exception message is.. if you put the break point on the line in your catch and hover over `file` variable whats in it..??

Comment: `this.ListView.View = View.LargeIcon;` have you thought that also the size of the image could be causing an issue.. have you considered re-sizing the ImageSize...??

Comment: I am not sure how 'thumbnaily" a 256x144 image is

Comment: well I could shrink it...but it really wouldn't help the problem as it just means more thumbnails can be drawn before it runs out of memory.  I think a more permanent solution is to draw only what is needed.

Comment: I just added all 2000 images from a 32x32 icon library to a listview - Four Times for 8000+ images - without a problem.  Taskmanager Working Set looks ok, and GDI objects is only 52.   Of course you will *eventually* run out of resources but 256x144 is pretty large.  The LV also has a virtual mode you might want to look into.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather tricky.

You have two problems:

- You need to know which Images you need to display
- You need to make sure that you don't run out of memory or GDI resources

Unfortunately the `ListView` doesn't help with Events or Properties that would notify you about scrolling or tell you which items are visible.

Here is a little piece of code that will do at least the latter; it load a few thousand filenames into a list images and keep a list of 100 items, last visible:

```
List<string> images = new List<string>();
List<int> visibleItems = new List<int>();

void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    // this loads the images on demand:
    if (!imageList1.Images.ContainsKey(images[e.ItemIndex]) ) 
       { loadImage(e.ItemIndex); e.Item.ImageIndex = imageList1.Images.Count - 1; }
    // this makes sure the listView is drawn by the system
    e.DrawDefault = true;

    // these lines would maintain a list of items that are or were recently visible
    if (!visibleItems.Contains(e.ItemIndex)) visibleItems.Add(e.ItemIndex);
    if (visibleItems.Count > 1000)
    {
       visibleItems.Clear(); 
       imageList1.Images.Clear();
       listView1.Invalidate();
    }

}

void loadImage(int index)
{
    imageList1.Images.Add(images[index], new Bitmap(images[index]) );
}
```

You need to set the `ListView.OwnerDraw = true;`; then the `DrawItem` event will be called and after setting `e.DrawDefault = true;` the actual drawing will be done by the system after all.

But the event will keep telling you exactly which Items are visible.

Now you can make sure that the respective Bitmaps are loaded in your ImageList or those far away are disposed again.. so far I have only implemented a load on demand only..

Update: Like Plutonix, I have runa few test and can load 3000 Images with 128x128 pixels each with out any problems at all. I load them on demand and it seems ImageList takes care of things quite nicely: No need to dispose of the Images, GDI resources stay at a low level (<100) for my thest program. The memory foorprint keep rising while I scroll but doesn't look as if it'll be a problem. It it is I can simply do a

```
imageList1.Images.Clear();
```

..and memory drops back to the starting point. Display works fine, reloading of the list starts without a glitch.. In fact I don't use the visibleItems list any longer.  I keep it in the answer, as it is a feasible way to know about these Items but atm I see no need for it..